# How to use previous row value for vertically merged cells in google sheets while fetching using pygsheets?

Tags: pygsheets

I am trying to get the data in the merged cell `Level 1` in all the smallest rows, or iterate over the rows created by the merged cells.

I am getting

```
[['Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'], ['', '', 'Level 3'], ['', '', 'Level 3']]
```

when I am fetching the data for the first 3 rows using `get_all_values` method.

The expectation is to get:

```
[['Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'], ['Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'], ['Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3']]
```

instead.

Currently I am using dictionaries to hold the data using a lot of logic to figure out the missing column data. Is there a better way of flattening the merged cells to their respective rows?

[image: Representation of google sheet with merged cells]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data begin at row #2, you can complete the column A by, in D2

```
=ArrayFormula(if($C2:$C="",,lookup(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)/if(A2:A<>"",1,0),A2:A)))
```

and to complete column B, in E2

```
=ArrayFormula(if($C2:$C="",,lookup(row(B2:B),row(B2:B)/if(B2:B<>"",1,0),B2:B)))
```

and in F2

```
=ArrayFormula(if($C2:$C="",,C2:C))
```

in this way you will get a complete set of data

Comment: I should have been a little more precise in the question, I was trying to find a way to get the data using pygsheets without modifying the google sheet in question. I have edited the question +1 for this answer..